# Working with Knockout 'foreach' looping through multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, knockout.js

I have a multidimensional associative array.

```
this.items = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "name1", viewable: true, children: [
        { name: "name1-1", viewable: true, children: []},
        { name: "name1-2", viewable: false, children: []}
    ] },
    { name: "name2", viewable: false, children: [] },
    { name: "name3", viewable: true, children: [
        { name: "name3-1", viewable: true, children: []},
    ] },
        { name: "name4", viewable: true, children: [] }
]);
```

The goal is to loop through this array and print out only the values that have 'viewable' set to true.

I have this working using a bunch of if and foreach statements, but the code is starting to get out of hand. This example only covers 2 levels buy my array can get up to **5 levels deep**, so this code is going to multiply and get ugly *really quick*.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <!-- ko if: viewable -->
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
        <!-- ko foreach: children -->
            <!-- ko if: viewable -->
            <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

So is there an easier/better way to loop through the entire array?

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/KSrzL/3/)

Comment: Do you have a proper resursive sturture? E.g. the items looks like the same on each level? In your sample some `children` are missing like: `{ name: "name1-1", viewable: true},` is this a requirement?

Comment: Oh, that's a typo. I can control that, so I figure that it's best to include 'children', even if it's empty. I edited my code and added children to all items. So, yes, all items will look the same on all levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) has some nice method working with arrays maybe you can use [flatten](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) and [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) to create one array from your structure then you can just write one `foreach`:

Or you could use templates to encapsulate your `if: viewable` logic and apply the template recursively:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
  <!-- ko if: viewable -->
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>    
        <!-- ko template: { name: 'template', foreach: $data.children } -->
        <!-- /ko -->    
  <!-- /ko -->
</script>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'template', foreach: items } ">
</ul>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XC3ZX/)

Comment: Sorry Chris, nemesv was a little quicker - I gotta give accepted answer to him. Thanks a lot for the help guys! This makes life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="ItemTemplate">
    <!-- ko if: viewable -->
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
        <!-- ko template: { name: 'ItemTemplate', foreach: children } --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

And then just:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'ItemTemplate', foreach: items }"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add empty children arrays on items you can use [template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)

[JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/damienobringer/KSrzL/5/)

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <idv data-bind="template: {name: 'mytemp'}" />
</ul>
<div data-bind="stopBinding:true">
    <div id="mytemp">
        <div data-bind="visible :viewable">
            <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
            <div data-bind="foreach: children">
                <div data-bind="template: {name: 'mytemp'}" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```