# Knockout.js loop over children of parent in table

Tags: json, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

My MVVM looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Company(data) {

    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.legal_form = ko.observable(data.legal_form);
    this.company_number = ko.observable(data.company_number);
    this.type_account = ko.observable(data.type_account);
    this.type_supplier = ko.observable(data.type_supplier);
    this.type_competitor = ko.observable(data.type_competitor);
    this.type_other = ko.observable(data.type_other);
    this.children = ko.observableArray(data.child);
}

function CompanyListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.companies = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON(Routing.generate('contacts_companies_get_json'), function(allData) {
        var mappedCompanies = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new Company(item) });
        self.companies(mappedCompanies);
    });  
}

ko.applyBindings(new CompanyListViewModel());

</script>
```

My View looks like this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: companies">
       <tr>
           <td>
               <a href="#" class="title">
                   <span data-bind="text: name"></span> <span data-bind="text: legal_form"></span>
               </a>        
           </td>
           <td data-bind="if:$data.company_number"><span data-bind="text: company_number"></span></td>
           <td><span data-bind="if: type_account" ><i class="icon-check"></i></span></td>
           <td><span data-bind="if: type_supplier" ><i data-bind="if: type_supplier" class="icon-check"></i></span></td>
           <td><span data-bind="if: type_competitor" ><i data-bind="if: type_competitor" class="icon-check"></i></span></td>
           <td><span data-bind="if: type_other" ><i data-bind="if: type_other" class="icon-check"></i></span></td>
           <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-mini">Details</a></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
```

I would like to add hidden `<tr>` for every child that a parent company has and add a plus sign before the parent to expand the hidden .

The problem is that I can only access the child within the original parent `<tr>` otherwhise will tell me "children" is not defined.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are the child companies only in the child array for a company, or are they also in the overall list of companies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) without a container element to display the children:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: companies">
       <tr>
           <!-- company columns -->
       </tr>
       <!-- ko foreach: children -->
           <tr>
              <!-- children columns -->
           </tr>
      <!-- /ko -->
</tody>
```

And with the help of a new property (like `showChildren` on the `Company`) you can do the show hide of the childrens:

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/B9jRZ/1/)

If you want to display the full hierarcy with the same columns so you want to have to display the children of the child campanies you can achieve with [recursive templates.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)
There were some questions about recursive templates latelly:

- [Recursive template with knockout js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525216/recursive-template-with-knockout-js)
- [Working with Knockout 'foreach' looping through multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814603/working-with-knockout-foreach-looping-through-multidimensional-array/15815413#15815413)