# Kendo template using nested / multidimension observable

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, observable

My goal is to create a simple navigation dropdown menu with nested levels ([like this](http://www.stunicholls.com/menu/pro_dropdown_1.html)). And I'd like to use an observable for it (unless there's a better solution).

```
var menuitems = ko.observable([
    { name: "item1", children: [
        { name: "item1-1", children: []},
        { name: "item1-2", children: []}
    ] },
    { name: "item2", children: [] },
    { name: "item3", children: [
        { name: "item3-1", children: []},
    ] },
    { name: "item4", children: [] }
]);
```

Then I'd use an unordered list to build the navigation...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>item1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>item1-1</a></li>
            <li><a>item1-2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>item2</a>
    </li>
    ... etc ...
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do this with a template. Maybe using a nested template or Kendo [hierarchical datasource](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/hierarchicaldatasource/custom-binding) with hasChildren or something?

This is very similar to a [previous SO question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814603/working-with-knockout-foreach-looping-through-multidimensional-array), but I'm no longer using Knockout.

Any ideas to accomplish this?

**Edit:**

I'm not sure if Kendo Menu is suitable. I need each nav item to load a view based off a few templates. So I'll have a data-tmpl-type attribute on each menu item so the app knows which template to load. I also need a data-view attribute to know which view to load into each template ...if that makes any sense.

I haven't figured out a way to do this with Kendo Menu.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your other question, I assume you want your menu to change based on attributes that might change in your data array.

You can do something like that by using the data structure you have as a data source for a kendoMenu, and react to changes by also creating a hierarchical data source with the data.

```
var data = [{
    text: "item1",
    enabled: true,
    items: [{
        text: "item1-1",
        enabled: true,
        items: []
    }, {
        text: "item1-2",
        enabled: true,
        items: []
    }]
}, {
    text: "item2",
    enabled: true,
    items: []
}, {
    text: "item3",
    enabled: true,
    items: [{
        text: "item3-1",
        enabled: true,
        items: []
    }]
}, {
    text: "item4",
    enabled: true,
    items: []
}];

$("#bindme").kendoMenu({
    dataSource: data
});

var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: data,
    change: function (e) {
        // enable / disable items in the menu
        var changedItem = e.items[0];
        var enabled = changedItem.enabled;
        var text = changedItem.text;
        var menuElem = $("#bindme").find(".k-link:contains(" + text + ")").parent();
        $("#bindme").data("kendoMenu").enable(menuElem, enabled);
    }
});
dataSource.read();

setTimeout(function () {
    dataSource.at(0).set("enabled", false);

}, 3000);
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/6B6cg/

Edit:
Not sure I completely understand the requirements, but here are a few more options that might be worth considering:

1. Take a look at this tutorial for a menu widget with templates: http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Kendo%20Music%20Store/Music%20Store%20Web/kendo-music-store-web-cart-menu-widget
2. use 'encoded: false' on your items so that the "text" property is interpreted as HTML - then you could add custom attributes
3. write a recursive function that traverses your data structure and writes the unordered list with whatever content you need; as you can see [in this example](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Kendo%20Music%20Store/Music%20Store%20Web/kendo-music-store-web-menu#add-the-about-pull-down-menu), you can put any kind of HTML into the items

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is pretty similar (exact?) what [`Kendo Menu`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/menu) widget does. Did you take a look into it?

Did you check [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html) demo?